# In cpp what is the difference between `new int` and `new int[1]`?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I am currently learning C++ and am struggling to understand what the difference is between the following two lines of code:

```
int* a = new int;
int* b = new int[1];
```

As far as I understand, both statements return an int pointer and only allocate space for 1 int on the heap. So, is there any practical difference between them, or are they just synonyms?

Comment: One is a single object and the other is an array of size one.  The look the same but are different types.

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike: If both can be assigned to a variable of the same type, what is it that is different about them?

Comment: `new int` yields a pointer to an `int`, `new int[1]` yields a pointer to an array of ints. You will have to deallocate `a` via `delete a` and `b` via `delete[] b`. Otherwise your program will have undefined behaviour and will most likely crash in practice

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think that ```delete b;``` would be UB.

Comment: Side notes : In practice both are unecessary use of new ;) In current C++ the [use of new/delete](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete) should be limited. For a dynamic resizable use std::vector<int> and if you need to allocate memory have a look at std::make_unique (instead of new)

Comment: @ScottHunter That's an invalid argument.  With `struct Foo { int cat; }; struct Bar : Foo { int dog; };` both `new Foo` and `new Bar` can be assigned to a `Foo*` but they have different types.

Comment: @Oersted `delete b;` is 100% UB.  `new`/`delete` or `new[]`/`delete[]`, any other combination is UB.

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike: A question can't be an invalid argument.  I was asking for clarification; you said they were different, and I was asking what the difference was.

Comment: @ScottHunter The difference is one points to an int, the other points to an int array so they require different deallocation methods.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replys so far, that being said I'm struggling to understand the practical difference. For example all of the following are identical between the two values e.g.   `a[0] = 1;  b[0] = 1;  sizeof(a); sizeof(b);  sizeof(*a);  sizeof(*b);`  as far as I can see so far the only difference is one needs `delete` and the other needs `delete []` ?

Comment: @ScottHunter In practice the difference is, that the compiler will allocate space _before_ the array with one element to store the number of elements, because that is a dynamic property. Then during deallocation with `delete[] b` the program will access that dynamic array size to properly be able to deallocate the array. All common allocators must know the size of the allocated memory region to deallocate it. To make life easy for programmers it has become a common method to simply store the size of the memory region in a header _before_ the pointer that is then handed out.

Comment: One difference between them is that `delete a` and `delete[] b` are well defined, whereas `delete [] a` and `delete b` both give undefined behaviour.    Essentially, the `delete` expression must correspond to the `new` expression.

Comment: @chrysante Thank you for explaining why they are different, I think that really helps some people understand better than just: "You must follow the rules because they are the rules". However, I also think it is important to stress that what you just explained is an implementation detail inside some specific compilers, and that any compiler is free to implement array allocation in the way they find best - so do NOT rely on this detail always being this way. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the other answers, the rules are the rules and if you want to write valid C++ that is guaranteed to work, even with future compilers, you must follow them.

However, in this case and most other cases where rules may seem arbitrary at first, there is a good reason for it:

The expression `new int[N]`, where `N` can be a value only known at runtime, yields a pointer to an array of `int`s. To deallocate it, you write `delete[] p`, where `p` is the result of the `new int[N]` expression. Note that you need to specify the array size to allocate, but not to deallocate.
Most common allocators which are used to implement `new` and `delete` however will need to know the size of the allocated memory region to deallocate it.
So what many compilers do, is allocate more memory than is necessary to store the array, take a little chunk in the beginning of the allocated memory region and store the size of the array in there. Then the pointer will be incremented to just past the region where the size is stored and returned to you. When you deallocate the array, the program will decrement the pointer, read the array size and pass the proper size of the memory region to the underlying allocators deallocation function.

Note that this is an implementation detail. You must not rely on the size being stored before the array. Some compilers might implement array allocation differently, but this is a common method. The C++ standard only specifies, that you must always match `new` with `delete` and `new[N]` with `delete[]`. Then the compiler is free to do with that whatever it wants or deems most efficient.

I should also note that the C++ committee *could have* decided to require you to explicitly pass the size of the array to `delete[]` like so:

```
delete [N] p;
```

But they haven't, perhaps because it may seem simpler to free the programmer from having to store the size themselves. I personally disagree with this decision but things are the way they are.

This is why, *in practice on most compilers*, `new int` and `new int[1]` will allocate differently sized memory regions and the result of `new int[1]` won't even point to the beginning of a memory region that was allocated by the underlying allocator. So when you try to deallocate your `b` pointer with `delete b` the allocator would get very confused because it would be given the  pointer `b` to deallocate which has never been handed out before.

---

Also the mandatory note: Always prefer `std::vector<T>` to `new T[N]` and `std::make_unique<T>(...)` to `new T(...)` unless you have a very good reason to choose the latter.

Comment: Will wait a short while before accepting to see if others have any comments or clarifications but so far to me this is the most clear and well explained answer that provides some understanding of the underlying differences.

Answer (score 3):

If you are learning C++, you should not care about *is there a difference here?*.

You should only remember:

- when I want to allocate a simple variable, I shall use `new` and `delete`.
- when I want to allocate an array, I shall use `new[]` and `delete[]`
- mixing both is forbidden

There are tons of examples where incorrect code is successfully processed by some compilers. There are even examples where where the compilers do document their processing as *extensions*, or for compatibility with legacy code.

But if you are learning C++ *now* you should only try to write correct code and never wonder if a slight variation could be accepted.

---

BTW as you were told in comment, direct use of explicit allocation should only occur in low level code, for example for a custom container implementation. In normal user code, just rely on the standard containers...

Comment: *when I want to allocate an array, I shall use* `std::vector` ;)

Comment: From a didactic standpoint I strongly disagree. I think knowing _why_ things are the way they are is helpful in understanding language language rules which otherwise may seem arbitrary. And in this case there is a very good reason that mixing `new` and `delete[]` or vice versa are forbidden, also in the case of one element arrays.

Comment: @chrysante: language rules are always arbitrary in the sense they are the rules for a specific language and may be different from the ones of a different language. If you want to become a language lawyer, understanding the reasons for rules does matter. If you just want to use a programming language, knowing (and respecting) the rules is enough. That being said, knowing the *philosophia* of a language **is** important. The problem with C++, is that it is intended to be used at different levels and because of that offers different *language philosophias*...

Comment: ... It can be used at a high level, almost like Java could be, or can be used at a very low level, almost like an assembly language could be. It is not an accident if the C standard library is included in the C++ one, nor if the standard pages here and there have references to the C language: C++ does want to be able to be used at low level as C is.

Comment: Maybe we have different notions of the word 'arbitrary', but to me probably none of the rules are arbitrary in the sense that people put a lot of thinking into each and every rule and decision. Thinking that is based on what the language shall archieve and how that can be efficiently implemented. Because C++ and Java have different goals and philosophys, different language rules arise from that thinking. You can of course simply learn the rules and call it a day, but I don't imagine that to be very rewarding or practical in the long term. Understanding why people

Comment: came up with the rules in the first place makes it much easier to memorize them imho.

Answer (score 2):

Pratically the only difference is that you must use the matching delete:

```
int* a = new int;
int* b = new int[1];

delete a;
delete[] b;
```

Conceptually however, the difference is in the type of object that is created. `new int` creates a single integer, an `int`. `new int[1]` on the other hand creates an array whose type is `int[1]`. In both cases you get a `int*` from the new expression. However, thats only due to c-arrays being a little quirky and `b` is not a pointer to the object you just created but a pointer to the first element of the array. The value of the two (array to first element and pointer to the array) is the same, but they are of different type and confusing the two can lead to lots of confusion down the line.

---

PS You shouldnt be using raw `new` in C++. Not for a single integer. And also not for arrays. There are smart pointers and `std::array` / `std::vector` for arrays.